# PROBLEMA CON CONSULTA SQL EN C# ASP .NET

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Tengo un proyecto webform en asp .net con c# y en mi consulta sql necesito datos que va a proporcionar el usuario.

El campo semana se ingresa en un textbox en el webform1 y la consulta la tengo en el webform2. De acuerdo a ese dato me va a mostrar ciertos registro en un gridview. Ademas del cod_user de inicio de sesion. A continuacion muestro el codigo

Errores:

> *'El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: String' de la linea:
>   int valor = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["semana"]);

*'La consulta con parámetros '(@cod varchar(5))SELECT bla bla' espera el parámetro '@cod', que no se ha proporcionado.'

**PAGINA ORIGEN**

```
   protected void BUTTON1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string semana = sem.Text;
       if (sem.Text != null)
       {
         Response.Redirect("webform2.aspx?semana=" + semana);
       }
       else {
           Response.Redirect("webform1.aspx");
       }
   }
```

**PAGINA DESTINO**

```
protectedvoid Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int valor = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["semana"]);// valor que viene de otro webform
       SqlConnection con = newSqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());

        con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = newSqlCommand("SELECT WHERE(Sem.Semana = '@sem') AND(Cab.Cod_user= '@cod') AND(etc...", con);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@sem", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 3);
        cmd.Parameters["@sem"].Value = valor;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);

cmd.Parameters["@cod"].Value = Session["Cod_user"]; 

SqlDataAdapter da = newSqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = newDataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
           gridview1.Visible = true;
           gridview1.DataSource = dt;
           gridview.DataBind();
         con.Close();
        }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme

Saludos

Gracias

Comment: Saludos girasol, ¿Podrías colocar la vista por favor? Gracias :D

Comment: hola, ya checaste el valor de tu variable de sesion Session["Cod_user"]?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx a la vista del error te refieres?

Comment: negativo, me refiero al archivo .aspx donde está tu formulario :D

Comment: @DMG hola el valor de esa variable, no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, pero ese codigo es con el que el usuario inicie sesion.. y pues usuarios hay muchos...

Comment: @fredyfx es una consulta enorme la cual de acuerdo a esos dos datos (cod_user..codigo de inicio de sesion del usuario y sem numero que el usuario va a escribir en un textbox)muestra los registros en un gridview

Comment: el textbox para la variable sem esta en un webform1 y el gridview en el webform2.

Comment: @sunflower aveces las variables de sesion pierden su valor, si puedes intenta cambiando la linea: cmd.Parameters["@cod"].Value = Session["Cod_user"];  por:  cmd.Parameters["@cod"].Value = Session["Cod_user"].ToString();  ve si te marca  error de conversion, te recomiendo ponerle un punto de interrupcion  ver los valores.

Comment: No crees que tu consulta esta mal "SELECT WHERE(Sem.Semana = '@sem') AND(Ca...", acaso no le falta el from y las columnas a seleccionar?

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara hola la escribi mal sin querer aqui, sucede que mi consulta es muy muy grande y le borre de mas

Comment: @DMG gracias lo he probado y ahora me muestra esto:

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.this[string].get devolvió null.

Comment: @sunflower checa esa variable de sesion porque en ese momento no existe como tal. prueba haciendo esto: Session["Cod_user"] = "valor para probar";  cmd.Parameters["@cod"].Value = Session["Cod_user"].ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes, verifica que tengas datos con las siguientes líneas de código

```
var requestSemana = Request.QueryString["semana"];
var laSessionActual = Session["Cod_user"]; 
int valor = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["semana"]); //Aquí coloca un breakpoint.
//De esta manera podrás ver la información de las 2 variables anteriores.
```

## Actualización

Para el Cod_User, reemplaza:

```
cmd.Parameters["@cod"].Value = Session["Cod_user"];
```

Por:

```
cmd.Parameters["@cod"].Value = (string)Session["Cod_user"];
```

Para la semana:

Reemplaza:

```
int valor = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["semana"]);
```

Por:

```
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["semana"]);
```

Comment: si los tengo amigo

Comment: acabo de actualizar la respuesta :)

Comment: gracias y para el campo semana?

Comment: actualizada, por cierto, de acuerdo a lo que dijiste en tu pregunta "El valor no puede ser nulo" y la respuesta "si los tengo" asumo que hay valor != null, por lo tanto, hay que convertir :)

Comment: ahora me ha arrojado este error 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto get devolvió null. en la linea: int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["semana"]);

Comment: momento, dijiste que tenías la información de ambas variables. Ese error es porque el Request.QueryString["semana"] es null y por lo tanto, al convertirlo genera ese error. ¿Estás accediendo desde el otro webform?

Comment: asi es, estoy accediendo desde otro webform

Comment: ¿Y ese webform está enviando correctamente la variable?

Comment: ya lo he corregido asi:  int valor = 0;
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["semana"], out valor);
y la query ha quedado asi:SqlCommand cmd = newSqlCommand("SELECT * from tabla WHERE semana="+valor+"...

Comment: ya no me arroja errores pero ahora la tabla me la muestra vacia

Comment: paso algo muy curioso mi link aparece asi: localhost:49236/Proyecto/webf1.aspx?semana= pero si yo le agrego un numero al link asi: webf1.aspx?semana=48, si me muestra los datos

Comment: Excelente! Por cierto, te muestra los datos porque el valor de "semana" es 48, y es != null

Comment: si me los muestra si yo agrego ese numero al link, pero si yo agrego el num a mi caja de textocomo debe ser no sale nada :c

Comment: Entonces sí te redirige del webform 1 al webform 2, ¿cierto?

Comment: si me redirige el problema ahora es ese que te comento @fredyfx

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74269/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-sunflower).