# ¿Pasa el valor de un textbox de un webform a otro? ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, webforms

Tengo un webform1 en el cual tengo un textbox sem.Text. Aqui esta el codigo para pasar ese

valor al un segundo webform

```
private string semana_x;
    public string semana
    {
        get
        {
                return semana_x;                
        }
       set
        {
         semana_x = value;
         this.sem.Text = value;
        }
    }


    protectedvoid b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("webf2.aspx?semana=" + semana);
    }
```

---

### webform 2

```
//aqui recibo el valor del webf1 y lo convierto a int

int valor;
int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["semana"], out valor);
//para compararlo con un campo de BD

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tabla where semana="+valor+",con);
//y mostrar todo en un gridview

SqlDataAdapter da = newSqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = newDataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
           gridview1.Visible = true;
           gridview1.DataSource = dt;
           gridview1.DataBind();
         con.Close();
        }
```

el problema es que cuando escribo el numero en el texbox no me muestra nada en la tabla y mi

link aparece asi: localhost:49236/Proyecto/webf2.aspx?semana=

pero si yo le agrego un numero al final

link asi: webf2.aspx?semana=48<-- asi, y si me muestra los datos en el gridview

Espero puedan ayudarme

Gracias

Saludos

Comment: y donde haces el set de semana? porque parece estar vacio.

Comment: hola gracias por responder, y eso como lo haria disculpa @gbianchi?

Comment: no se como esta estructurado tu programa. Pero por lo que veo, semana recibe un valor (de quien) y lo pasa a un txt.. querras haber hecho lo contrario? que el usuario cargue el txt y vos lo pases a semana?

Comment: si el usuario va a escribir el num en el txt y ese numero se va a comparar con un campo  semana de la BD para poder mostrar los datos en un gridview

Comment: Entonces, sin mirar la clase que recibe (el webform 2), el webform 1 esta mal, porque el valor que esta en el txt nunca se lo estas pasando a la propiedad semana. es mas, no deberias ni redireccionar si ese valor esta vacio. A ver, pongo una respuesta con ese problema. y despues si tenes otro lo vemos en otra pregunta.

Comment: [Posbilemente Duplicada] https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144570/problema-con-consulta-sql-en-c-asp-net/144579?noredirect=1#comment271488_144579  Girasol ¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por todo lo que hablamos en los comentarios, los valores ingresados en tu webform, no estan siendo pasados a tu clase.

Tu propieda deberia ser algo asi:

```
private string semana_x;
public string semana
{
    get
    {
        return semana_x;                
    }
   set
    {
        semana_x = value;
    }
}
```

En algun lado, deberias cargar ese valor en esa propiedad. Solo como ejemplo, vamos a suponer que lo hacemos en el click (algo que no tiene mucho sentido, porque si lo hacemos ahi, mandemoslo directamente)

```
protectedvoid b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    semana = this.sem.Text;
    Response.Redirect("webf2.aspx?semana=" + semana);
}
```

Algo estas pensando mal si armaste la propiedad de la forma que la habias armado. Revisa conceptos sobre eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado

Answer (score 2):

Puedes enviarla tambien en una session y recuperarla en la siguiente de destino.

```
protectedvoid b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["variable"] = semana;
    Response.Redirect("webf2.aspx);
}
```

---

```
var semana = Session["variable"];
```